# How to set SWF object to the background of the Flex 4 Application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, background

I am Creating one application in which I want to set one swf as my application background.

I am able to set background but it is only coming with some area only.

It is not coming in the whole application.

It is not scaled in the whole application background.


I am using 9-slice scaling with that background SWF.

Please Help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary:** To accomplish this in a **Flex 4** Application you should create a custom Application Skin and add the .swf you want to use as a DisplayObject that sits behind the `contentGroup` Group.

**Implementation:**

Create a new skin, e.g., SWFBackgroundSkin.mxml, and make sure the skin is set to have a host component compatible with the spark Application class:

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]
</fx:Metadata>
```

Next, add an SWFLoader as the *first* visible element (ie. behind `contentGroup`), which will serve as the background:

```
<mx:SWFLoader source="background.swf"/>
...
<s:Group id="contentGroup" ... />
```

Finally, in the main Application, set the skinClass:

```
<s:Application ... skinClass="skins.SWFBackgroundSkin">
```

assuming the SWFBackgroundSkin.mxml is in the `skins` package (folder).

**Note:** You may want to have a look at the default Application skin, spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin, first.  If you make your new skin from the default one, make sure to either delete the `<s:Rect id="background" ... >` or at least put the SWFLoader in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But still it is not coming in the full area. It is just coming in the size of the loaded swf area only. Can you give me any sample application ?

Comment: I simplified my answer.  As for the scaling, if you add `width="100% height="100%" scaleContent="true"` to the SWFLoader, it should scale to the full stage.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us how and where you add the background, but something like this should work:

```
stage.addChildAt (background, 0);
```

For the scaling, add an event listener to the stage to react on Event.RESIZE:

```
stage.addEventListener (Event.RESIZE, function () : void { 
    background.width = stage.stageWidth;
    background.height = stage.stageHeight;
});
```

Comment: When I am putting event handler in the creationComplete handler of my AIR windowApplication class, it is giving error of can not access property of null object of the stage class.

Comment: Use the applicationComplete handler instead - creationComplete is fired before the objects actually appear on the stage.